# Why does imap_fetchbody return cryptic data?

Tags: php

I have a script that is reading mails from a mail account and writing the content into files. This is working well besides there are some mails, that can not be read.

Here is some of the code

```
$mails = imap_search($imap,'UNSEEN');
foreach($mails as $mail)
{
  $content_type = imap_fetchmime($imap,$mail,1);
  $message = imap_fetchbody($imap,$mail,1);
  //$message = imap_fetchbody($imap,$mail,1.1);
  //$message = imap_fetchbody($imap,$mail,2);

  $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $mail);
  if(isset($structure->parts[1]))
  {
    $part = $structure->parts[1];
  }
  $encoding = $part->encoding;
}
```

The problem is `$message` is a long cryptic string, that I am not able to decrypt, and all other variables are empty `($content_type, $structure, $encoding)`. I have tried all decryption methods I know, but had no success. When I change the option of `imap_fetchbody` to 1.1 or 2 I get nothing back.

Comment: is it possible these messages have been run through PGP to encrypt them?

Comment: I dont know what PGP is. I just read it is some decryption method? Can I somehow test, if it has been run through PGP?

Comment: PGP - `Pretty Good Privacy` ~ end to end encryption of messages using public and private keys. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy ~ If the messages have been encrypted all you will see is gobbledegook characters and have no way, without the correct key, to ever read it

Comment: What does the `Content-type` header of the message contain?